# Delayed Payment in Stripe Connect to unknown user

Tags: c#, stripe-payments

I'm writing a service which allows users to sign up for classes, at the time of sign up the class instructor may not be known, but I need to create a pending charge to assure that the instructor will be paid.  Later I want to update the pending and set a finalization date, e.g update the instructors account Id and 24 hours after the class ends pay the instructor

I'm trying to understand the work flow of how to do it, but the API Doc's don't seem to be helpful.

I have a service to create Payment Intents like so:

```
var paymentIntentService = new PaymentIntentService();
var paymentIntentTransferDataOptions = new PaymentIntentTransferDataOptions();

var options = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
{
    Amount = paymentIntentTransactionOptions.AmountInCents,
    Currency = DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_CURRENCY,
    ApplicationFeeAmount = this.CalculateApplicationFee(paymentIntentTransactionOptions),
    ReceiptEmail = "", // TODO Obtain this from the Logged in user
    PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> { "card" },
};

var requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.IdempotencyKey = INTENT_IDEM_PREFIX + paymentIntentTransactionOptions.TransactionId;
var paymentIntent = await paymentIntentService.CreateAsync(options, requestOptions);
```

I would like to create a pending charge with no destination at first and before completion I will update the user to send it to.

The update process I would assume to just, call Get on the PaymentIntent and Update the Sender.

My confusion lays around 3 areas.

1. How does the API Know what user I'm allowed to send on behalf of a user?
   e.g I just provide an accountId.  Does the api have full control of other accounts after registration?
2. How can I Create a pending charge, to assure the instructor gets paid, does that happen when I create the payment intent?
3. How do I finalize the transaction (Now, or preferable with a future date)

Comment: Taking a quick glance at the API doc you should be able to create an intent and update it later. only the amount and currency are required. https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create?lang=dotnet

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks, my confusion more lies in, the confirmation, what will trigger the payment to send,  give me a second I'll update the question for clarification

Comment: Have you seen  these use cases docs as yet https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/use-cases#connected-accounts

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks that answers most of my questions.  I've clarified my questions to be more coherent, so they will be more useful to the community in the future.  I'll write up an answer to the question later today, but If you wanted to put down a short answer I would gladly accept it, and make a few edits later with some of the specifics

Comment: No worries. I am not familiar enough in the topic to warrant an answer. I just pointed you to the docs where I thought you would get the relevant details. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently created an entire sharing economy platform with Stripe Connect, so I'm fairly familiar with it.

**Charging the User:** You'll need to create a regular charge for the user after they schedule the class. Read this on [creating charges](https://stripe.com/docs/charges). This will charge the user $X and hold it in the platforms account without yet transferring it.

**Paying the Instructor:** You'll need to create a separate transfer using `source_transaction` to send the money to the instructor's account. `source_transaction` will basically just make the transfer from the charge you made earlier from the customer. You can read more about that [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#transfer-availability).

Regarding holding the funds for 24hrs, if you use `source_transaction`, the money won't become available for payout until after 2 days due to processing. You can read more about that [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-balances). If you want it to become available faster, you have 2 options. Either you can enable [Instant Payout](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-balances) (which I don't recommend) or you can have a reserve balance in your platform stripe balance to cover the one-day layover and then you can make the transfers without `source_transaction`.

Comment: Thanks I'll investigate this

Comment: I'm confused why do I need to create a seperate charge,  isn't the purpose of a paymentIntent, a way to create an intent to pay the instructor?

Comment: Well, you don't have to. You have 3 options, which is laid out clearly here... https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges
I just like the separate approach because it gives greater flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, for the help!

Comment: So I'm still playing around with this, but just to be sure this way will transfer the money through the platform correct making me incharge of disputes and fees right?

Comment: Correct, but I would check with stripe to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after asking a few more questions and reading api docs.  There are a few ways of doing this.  @nachshonf answer will  get the job done.  However if I use transfers and seperate charges, The platform will be responsible for the Stripe fees and refund.

Instead I've come up with a more complex way of doing this, but will assure less of a headache for me in the long run.   Basically I create a hold via the platform, and then when the instructor is resolved will request to issue another charge for the instructor.  This way all disputes go through the instructor.

First off I'll create a hold via the platform,  This is pretty simple

```
public Task<PaymentIntent>CreatePlatformHoldAsync(long amountInCents, string customerId,
    string paymentMethodId, string idem = null, string currency = DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_CURRENCY)
{
    var paymentIntentService = new PaymentIntentService();
    var options = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
    {
        Amount = amountInCents,
        Currency = currency,
        //ReceiptEmail = "", // TODO Obtain this from the Logged in user
        PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> { "card" },
        CustomerId = customerId,
        PaymentMethodId = paymentMethodId,
        CaptureMethod = "manual",
    };

    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions { IdempotencyKey = idem };
    return paymentIntentService.CreateAsync(options, requestOptions);
}

/// <summary>
/// Confirm a payment intent, on the platform or sellerAccount
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sellerStripeAccountId">optional, omit for the platform confirm</param>
public Task<PaymentIntent> ConfirmPaymentAsync(string paymentIntentId,
    string sellerStripeAccountId = null)
{
    var paymentIntentService = new PaymentIntentService();
    var paymentIntentConfirmOptions = new PaymentIntentConfirmOptions();

    var options = new RequestOptions
    {
        StripeAccount = sellerStripeAccountId
    };

    return paymentIntentService.ConfirmAsync(paymentIntentId, 
        paymentIntentConfirmOptions, options);
}
```

First create a hold, Then confirm it to authorize the charges.   Then I'll create another charge for the instructor

```
public Task<PaymentIntent> CreateDestinationChargeAsync(long amountInCents, long applicationFeeInCents, 
    string paymentMethodId, string destinationAccountId, string idem = null, 
    string currency = DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_CURRENCY)
{

    var paymentIntentService = new PaymentIntentService();
    var options = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
    {
        Amount = amountInCents,
        Currency = currency,
        ApplicationFeeAmount = applicationFeeInCents,
        //ReceiptEmail = "", // TODO Obtain this from the Logged in user
        PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> { "card" },
        PaymentMethodId = paymentMethodId,
    };

    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions
    {
        IdempotencyKey = idem,
        StripeAccount = destinationAccountId
    };

    return paymentIntentService.CreateAsync(options, requestOptions);
}
```

After this is paid you can cancel the platform hold or wait 7 days for the hold to age away.

**Edit For Usages**

```
public async Task<Customer> CreateCustomerAsync(string email, string sourceToken)
{
    var options = new CustomerCreateOptions
    {
        Email = email, // "paying.user@example.com",
        Source = sourceToken,
    };
    var service = new CustomerService();
    return await service.CreateAsync(options);
}

/// <summary>
/// Creates a payment method for a customer on the sellers stripe account 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task<PaymentMethod> CreatePaymentMethodAsync(string customerId, string paymentMethodId,
    string stripeConnectAccountId)
{
    var paymentMethodService = new PaymentMethodService();
    var paymentMethodOptions = new PaymentMethodCreateOptions
    {
        CustomerId = customerId,
        PaymentMethodId = paymentMethodId
    };

    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
    {
        StripeAccount = stripeConnectAccountId
    };

    return await paymentMethodService.CreateAsync(paymentMethodOptions, requestOptions);
}
```

Usage:

```
//set destination here
var destinationAccountId = "";   

var configuration = this.GetConfiguration();
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = configuration["Stripe:ClientSecret"];
//This is the name of the service which I define the methods above
var stripeService = new StripeConnectService(configuration);
//"tok_mastercard" is a test value to represent a paymentToken
var customer = await stripeService.CreateCustomerAsync("CustomerEmail@gmail.com", "tok_mastercard");
var sharedPaymentMethod = await stripeService.CreatePaymentMethodAsync(customer.Id, 
    customer.DefaultSourceId, destinationAccount.AccountId);
var paymentIntent = await stripeService.CreateDestinationChargeAsync(1000, 100, 
    sharedPaymentMethod.Id, destinationAccountId);
await stripeService.ConfirmPaymentAsync(paymentIntent.Id, destinationAccountId);
```

These are examples and are not meant for production I'm only using them to test the flow.

**Note:** the payment token represents a customer.  I haven't implemented a way to obtain the payment token but it looks like you will need stripe.js so they can enter there card information to create a token.

Comment: Just fixed some of the syntax. Since nothing else is being awaited except for the return then async-await is not really needed. Just return the task.

Comment: Thanks Nkosi, Yeah it took me a while to find the right solution.  My main concern was that I didn't want to be in the middle of the disputes between customers.  Stripes documentation looks nice, but they are missing key links to figure out the full picture.   E.g They don't show how to attach a customer, or how that customer gets payment methods or how, you get the credit cards into their system.  A lot of this was searching so i figured I'd share the knowledge

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip on async, that should clean up some of my code